# Query string 'p=12' in url redirect to permalink post 'site.com/post-permalink'

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

When the user tape www.site.com/p=12 the user is redirected to www.site.com/post-permalink
I want to disable redirection for 'p=' ! I want that the post be able just with the permalink.
How can i disable this ?

Comment: It sounds like you are saying you want a page that is hit directly at `?p=1` to NOT redirect to the clean url. Is that correct?

Comment: If you go to Settings -> Permalinks and choose **Default** in the format of permalinks. Would that work for you?